# For loop algorithm to print right triangle with characters

Tags: java, algorithm, console

Trying to print to console a text isoscles triangle of arbitrary size like below:

[image]

I've done transformation algorithms like this before but the fact its drawing just the shape outline is throwing me for a loop. The triangles side is stored in the class as int leg, and so far this is all I can think to do when creating the algorithm.

```
for (int i = 0; i < leg - 1; i++){
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: hint: you need two loops

Comment: Scary Wombat, I assumed as much, but I'm struggling to decide what that for loop does.

Comment: right - first loop is for vertical, second is for horizontal

Comment: the size of second loop is index of first loop.  If counter of second loop is frist index or last index then print

Comment: Scary Wombat, that almost got my mind going with it, but not quite. if the second loop is j < i it doesnt get anywhere unless I missinterpreted the part about the size of j being i

Answer (score 1):

If you describe in text what each line is, you'll see there are three patterns, and the middle pattern needs a loop:

```
o         1 'o' character
oo        2 'o' characters, separated by 0 spaces
o o       2 'o' characters, separated by 1 space
o  o      2 'o' characters, separated by 2 spaces
o   o     2 'o' characters, separated by 3 spaces
oooooo    6 'o' characters
```

Printing X spaces needs a second loop, inside to middle pattern loop.

Printing X `'o'` characters needs a third loop.

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I'm actually trying to get it spaces out something like this.

Answer (score 0):

As Andreas points out it seems easiest to loop according to how many spaces you need:

```java
public class f {

    static void g(int n){
        if(n>1){
            System.out.println("o");
            String spaces = "";
            for(int i=0;i<n-2;i++){
                System.out.println("o"+spaces+"o");
                spaces+=" ";
            }
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++) System.out.print("o");
        }
        else System.out.println("o");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        g(6);
    }
}
```